# In K-NN How to show the set of k cases that was used to make the correct prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I trained and tested a model that predicts the sales using K-NN with `(k=10)` in python.

```
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=10, algorithm="brute") 
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn_pred = knn.predict(X_test) 
test_data['predictied'] = knn_pred
```

I want to show the set of 10 cases that was selected by K-NN to make the prediction for each row.
How can I show or retrieve that `k` cases?

Comment: Any other ideas on how to find k nearest neighbors for specific row that could be applied to my code?

Comment: why is this one not suiting you?

Comment: you would be most welcome to accept the answers when using them in your code. This would help storing the questions as "answered". especially when opening new one using this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html)

> kneighbors(self, X=None, n_neighbors=None, return_distance=True)
>
> Finds the K-neighbors of a point. Returns indices of and distances to
> the neighbors of each point.

this method will return the distances and index of the points used to compute the value

Comment: `for t in X_test: print(knn.kneighbors(t,n_neighbors=10,return_distance=False))`